# SQlite sort naturally

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of data like this:

```
Index       Stage_Id    
1           V8R0.11.0     
2           V8R0.10.0     
3           V8R0.9.0        
4           V8R0.8.0        
5           V8R0.7.0        
6           V8R0.6.0        
7           V8R0.5.0        
8           V8R0.4.0        
9           V8R0.3.0        
10          V8R0.2.0       
11          V8R0.1.0        
12          V8R0.13.0       
12          V8R0.12.0        
12          V8R0.11.0
```

I want to sort it naturally, i.e., the last three records should came before V8R0.11.0.

Answer (score 0):

`instr` searches for the position of the first period; `substr` extracts all of the string followung that; and the `CAST` converts that into a number, ignoring everything after the second period:

```
SELECT *
FROM ATableOfData
ORDER BY CAST(substr(Stage_Id, instr(Stage_Id, '.') + 1) AS INTEGER)
```